# TypeScript: How to support Intellisense for importing CSS files with alias path from compilerOptions.paths?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Basically as the title. I want to be able to import with intellisense for a CSS file where its path contains one of the aliases I defined by `compilerOptions.paths` of tsconfig.json. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

For example,

```
import * as styles from '@mystyles/somestyle.module.css'
```

during the typing of `@mystyles` it should already show that `somestyle.module.css` in its completion menu. Currently it doesn't.

and the tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@mystyles/*": [ "src/reactApp/styles/*" ],
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "public/**/*"
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I know you better than anyone else. So let me solve your problem.

1. You're writing JS. To make your tsconfig.json affect those JS files, you have to set `checkJs: true` in your tsconfig.json.
2. TypeScript by default know nothing about the extension `.css`. So to make TS recognize it, you have to create a `.d.ts` file for CSS files. You will get intellisense for CSS files.
3. You have set tsconfig.json correctly for path alias. Nothing needs to be done in this step.
4. Finally, and most importantly, you're using webpack and you have to setup its `resolve.alias` correctly to do the dirty work transpiling those alias paths into expanded real file paths.

I hope this help!